# Three-digit year in date on Chinese document

Tags: translation

For work, I occasionally have to translate foreign language documents. I've been running into a lot of Chinese (simplified) documents that have a date listed as `YYY/MM/DD`.

Why is the year only 3 digits? Is this just a typo?

Comment: Could you provide an example and some more context?

Comment: Here's an example of the format: 102年03月01日 
I recognize that it's in Japanese, but the rest of the document is listed as Chinese (simplified).

Comment: Are these documents from Taiwan, by any chance? In that case the calendar system is that of the Chinese Republic (Starting with 1912 as base year).

Comment: Though,  you say they are in Simplified Chinese...

Comment: Well, Google translate detects Chinese and then translates it correctly to English from there. But yes, it is a document from a Taiwan-based company. How do I determine what the year is on these documents, given this calendar system?

Comment: I usually just subtract 11, look at the last two digits, and then treat it as a two digit short form for year. There are tools online to convert the dates for you as well.

Comment: Oops sorry, I went the wrong way. I add 11 if I'm looking at TW years. I subtract 11 if I'm converting from western calendar to TW years.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By now you have figured out, why the years are represented as YYY, but just to make this post not look like many of those stubs on this site, here's a more detailed answer to anyone stumbling upon this page in the future.

**Taiwan** (officially styled the Republic of China) still uses the **Republican calendar** (or [Minguo calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minguo_calendar)), alongside the international calendar system of Western origin. This is known as **民國紀元** (民国纪元 in simplified Chinese, though not used in Mainland China). It follows the dynastic/feudal time keeping of **numbering years consecutively** after the ascension to throne of the current emperor, with the exception that there is no sort of emperor or king in the [Republican era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_China_%281912%E2%80%9349%29) (although, [Yuan Shi-kai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_Shikai) made a faint attempt, and resigned from his throne almost exactly 100 years ago). A similar system is still in place in **Japan**, used parallel to the Western calendar, and probably even [more extensively used, with era names, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar) than the Republican calendar in modern day Taiwan.

The practical way to work with it is not that difficult. Here's the formula:

```
Republican calendar Year = Western calendar Year - 1911
```

So this year is 105年. For those who can work with Tradional characters, here's a sophisticated [online calculator](http://sinocal.sinica.edu.tw/). Here's the output for this month:

[image]

*(The bold face digits are the days according to the Western calendar, the smaller digits show the month/day in the Chinese calendar, in this case the lunar calendar is used, which is the basis of observing Chinese New Year, etc.)*

This elaborate system of Chinese time keeping and [age reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_age_reckoning) have their many intricacies, but the above is probably enough for you  to get the gist.